# How do I get rid of the [regular] tag next to my bullet point in my itemized list in Latex?

Tags: latex

```
\section{EXPERIENCE}
{\begin{itemize}
  \item Optimized multiple old data load processes to run \textbf{40-70\%} faster.
\end{itemize}
}
```

The output for this is

`○[regular] Optimized multiple old data load processes to run 40-70% faster.`

How do i get rid of the `[regular]` next to the bullet point? I'm using overleaf, but have tried other online latex editors and all have the same output.

Comment: Hello. In case you wouldn't have a reply, you might try this Stack: https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Always make a compilable [mre] so we can reproduce the problem. What you describe is not standard behaviour and probably caused by your class or packages.